# Is there any way to share type between object properties only by provided value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, next.js, react-tsx

I want to make React table custom component with row selection in single, multiple and none selection mode. And since is refactoring process of current oversized table component I want to make it as simple as possible in case of setup and props.

I tried some attempts with `infer` and unions like this:

```js
type SimpleTableSelectionOptionsSingle = {
  selected: string | null;
  onChange: (selected: string | null) => void;
};


type SimpleTableSelectionOptionsMultiple = {
  selected: string[];
  onChange: (selected: string[]) => void;
};

type SimpleTableSelectionOptions<T extends string | string[] | null> = T extends string
  ? SimpleTableSelectionOptionsSingle
  : T extends string[]
  ? SimpleTableSelectionOptionsMultiple
  : never;

type Props = {
//...other props
selectionOptions?: SimpleTableSelectionOptions<???>
}
```

But I'm ended up providing some default generics types to SimpleTableSelectionOptions. I wanted to specify type between `string` | `string[]` | `null` by provided data. And kinda obvious that `null` and `string` should be specified in pair, just like `string[]` and `[]` - empty string array (but here's no type required). I'm asking here, because I don't even know if it's possible to achieve props like:

```js
<SimpleTable 
//...other props
selectionOptions={{
selected: 'some-id', // Since this is string
onChange: (selected) => { /* something... */ }, // selected here also needs to be string 
}}
/>
```

AND in the same time:

```js
<SimpleTable 
//...other props
selectionOptions={{
selected: ['some-id', 'some-other-id'], // Since this is Array<string>
onChange: (selected) => { /* something... */ }, // selected here also needs to be Array<string> 
}}
/>
```

I tried also some helper functions but they're not so handy, like normal infered types and I wanted to avoid them. I know how to handle checks and setup in javascript to make it working. Only thing that I can't handle is types definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there we go!
This is handled for selections. I needed to cast them anyway.

```js
const handleSelection = useCallback(
    (row: T) => {
      if (!selectionOptions) {
        return;
      }

      const { selected, setSelected } = selectionOptions;

      if (Array.isArray(selected)) {
        const typedSelected = selected as string[];
        const typedSetSelected = setSelected as (selected: string[]) => void;

        if (typedSelected.includes(row.id)) {
          typedSetSelected(typedSelected.filter((id) => id !== row.id));
        } else {
          typedSetSelected([...typedSelected, row.id]);
        }
      } else if (typeof selected === 'string') {
        const typedSelected = selected as string;
        const typedSetSelected = setSelected as (selected: string | null) => void;

        if (typedSelected === row.id) {
          typedSetSelected(null);
        } else {
          typedSetSelected(row.id);
        }
      }
    },
    [selectionOptions]
  );
```

And here's typings:

```js
interface SimpleTablePropsSelectionSingle<T extends SimpleTableDataType>
  extends SimpleTablePropsBase<T> {
  selectionOptions?: {
    selected: string | null;
    setSelected: (selected: string | null) => void;
  };
}

interface SimpleTablePropsSelectionMultiple<T extends SimpleTableDataType>
  extends SimpleTablePropsBase<T> {
  selectionOptions?: {
    selected: string[];
    setSelected: (selected: string[]) => void;
  };
}

export type SimpleTableProps<T extends SimpleTableDataType> =
  | SimpleTablePropsSelectionSingle<T>
  | SimpleTablePropsSelectionMultiple<T>;
```

With this, when `selected` is `string[]`: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Making SimpleTable a generic function, as such

```
type SimpleTableSelectionOptionsSingle = {
  selected: string | null;
  onChange: (selected: string | null) => void;
};

type SimpleTableSelectionOptionsMultiple = {
  selected: string[];
  onChange: (selected: string[]) => void;
};

type SimpleTableSelectionOptions<T extends string | string[] | null> =
  T extends string
    ? SimpleTableSelectionOptionsSingle
    : T extends string[]
    ? SimpleTableSelectionOptionsMultiple
    : never;

type Props<T extends string | string[] | null> = {
  //...other props
  selectionOptions?: SimpleTableSelectionOptions<T>;
};

const SimpleTable = <T extends string | string[] | null>(props: Props<T>) => {
  const { selectionOptions } = props;
  const { selected, onChange } = selectionOptions ?? {};
  // ...
  return <></>;
};

export default SimpleTable;
```

You can now use `SimpleTable`

```
<SimpleTable<string>
  selectionOptions={{
    selected: "1",
    onChange: (selected) => {
      console.log(selected);
      //          ^ string | null
    },
  }}
/>
<SimpleTable<string[]>
  selectionOptions={{
    selected: ["1", "2"],
    onChange: (selected) => {
      console.log(selected);
      //          ^ string[]
    },
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I forget to mention, that I'm using already one infered value for props. Maybe I can use second one for selection..? I didn't know this declaration (`
<SimpleTable<string[]>`), need to check this out. Thanks! Current props are like 
```export type SimpleTableBodyProps<T extends SimpleTableDataType> = {
  columns: SimpleTableColumn<T>[];
  data: T[];
  renderEmptyResult?: RenderEmptyResultFn;
  selectionControls: SimpleTableSelectionType;
  selectionOptions?: SimpleTableSelectionOptions<any>;
};```

Comment: Ok, like this I've got inside `if (Array.isArray(selected))`  - `onChange()` with type `onChange: (selected: string & string[]) => void` - definitely should be `string[]` if `selected` is `string[]` there

Answer (score 0):

You might need [discriminating unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), I guess. Check this out and let me know whether this is something you are expecting:

```
type SimpleTableSelectionOptionsSingle = {
  selected: string | null;
  onChange: (selected: string | null) => void;
};


type SimpleTableSelectionOptionsMultiple = {
  selected: string[];
  onChange: (selected: string[]) => void;
};

type SimpleTableSelectionOptions = SimpleTableSelectionOptionsSingle | SimpleTableSelectionOptionsMultiple;

type Props = {
//...other props
selectionOptions?: SimpleTableSelectionOptions
}
```

Comment: Tried already something very similar. They're merging. When `selected` is a string, then `onChange` is `(string & string[]) => void`. They can't be merged with generics, but then I need to provide a type argument or default one and it's still not the type I wanted, because it's merging all three modes.

Comment: try this, not something similar - try DISCRIMINATING UNION, it is a feature of TypeScript based on UNION. It is not the same what you've done before I guess. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

Comment: No, I mean I didn't mention this in original post, but this code was exactly the same I tried before posting. The only difference is `(selected: string | null) => void;` presence of null here. I tried without null. But ok, maybe previously I just messed something up. Got to try this tommorow at work, thanks :D

Comment: Still nothing. I made it again with everything proposed and with `string[]` at `selected` I've got `onChange: (selected: any) => void` - returns `any` in the props and in the component it's `string | string[] | null` . Can't even typecheck correctly, because without generics `selected` and `onChange` are not connected.